# Web App on LAN VM: curl -L works from other vms, browser/curl on host doesn't

Tags: hadoop, curl, networking, port, hadoop-yarn

I am in the process of setting up a Hadoop cluster of virtual machines on my LAN and a process on one of the vms (the ResourceManager) provides a Web UI which is exhibiting strange behavior.  All vms run from my desktop and have been assigned ips.

The URL I am targeting is `resourcemanager:8088` and here is the behavior.

From other vms running on my desktop:

```
curl -v resourcemanager:8088
```

returns an `HTTP 302 Found` response with `Location: http://resourcemanager:8088/cluster`.  Looking this up I saw this is a redirect, and `curl -L resourcemanager:8088` *successfully retrieves the HTML*.

From the desktop running the vms:

Trying to reach the URL from (Chrome) browser gives `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.  Also

```
curl resourcemanager:8088
```

returns `curl: (7) Failed to connect to resourcemanager port 8088: Connection refused`.

Each vm has the same **/etc/hosts**:

```
::1       localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost
10.0.0.3  namenode
10.0.0.4  resourcemanager
10.0.0.5  datanode1
```

and the `.../drivers/etc/hosts` file on my (Windows) desktop looks the same minus the `localhost` lines.

To make matters more complicated, a second process (the NameNode) also provides a web ui, call it `namenode:50070`, and I *am able* to `curl` it from both the desktop *and* vms, *and* I can get to it via browser from my desktop.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Specs:

Desktop OS: Windows 10

VMs OS: Arch Linux latest (Linux kernel 4.5.4)

An initial Arch+hadoop VM was created with Hyper-V, then [cloned](https://techjourney.net/how-to-clone-vm-virtual-machine-in-hyper-v/) to create the three "cluster" vms listed above.  After cloning, each vm was given a unique hostname (listed above) and assigned a reserved IP address from my router (also listed above).  All VMs use an ["external vm switch"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_virtual_switch).

Comment: What networking type are the VM's using?  Normally, the host can't access the guest VM's via networking unless you set up forwarding rules.  Consider the VM network to have a firewall, which in your current setup allows other VMs to talk to eachother, but your desktop may as well be a computer on the other side of the firewall which is why you can't get in.

Comment: What do you mean "networking type"?  When creating the vms in hyper-v I first created an "external virtual switch" which they all use.  Also, there is another web app running on *another* VM (namenode:50070) and I am able to access it from my desktop browser and via curl, and also via curl from the other vms as well.  I don't why the behavior between the two would be different.  Since the web apps come along with the hadoop framework, I am not sure if/how/why they are setup differently.  But it may just be a networking issue aside from hadoop

Comment: Is that OS any different, maybe an OS firewall like iptables?

Comment: I added some extra details in the "Edit," but all VMs were [cloned](https://techjourney.net/how-to-clone-vm-virtual-machine-in-hyper-v/) from the same ArchLinux+hadoop template VM but given unique hostnames and IPs.  So all networking configurations on them should be the same.  Aside from the fact that the Web UIs are running on distinct (but nearly identical) VMs, the only difference I can see is the port.

Comment: Hm that's tricky.  The networking seems fine then with the type you chose.  Connection refused means something is actively rejecting the connection though, so you are reaching a destination (possibly the wrong one) and it is refusing the connection.  As opposed to a timeout where packets are just lost or dropped.  I don't have much experience with Hadoop, but is there some configuration that might be denying the connection because its coming from a different subnet? (or does your desktop also have a 10.0.0.x local address?

Comment: Host machine (my desktop) is 10.0.0.2.  I've also read that I may be getting connection refused when the URL is expecting a POST, but it received a GET.  However, curl from the vms doesn't give connection refused (in fact curl -L WORKS), and I doubt the web app ui homepage is configured for POST.  I am not even sure how to keep debugging this.

Comment: At this point I'd suggest running Wireshark on your host machine and capturing a session where you get the connection refused reply.  Then you can at least confirm via MAC address and IP whether or not it's the guest VM refusing the connection and not something in the middle.  Are there any other open ports on that guest you can test to see if are accessible or not?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment, because I do not have 50 reputation yet, but that might have to do with the configuration of the service behind port 8088: The VM probably got a 'small' netmask from the virtual dhcp server, which presumably covered the IP range of all other VMs, not including the host machine. If that had happened and the service was configured like many others -to listen on all interfaces- it would not react on requests and your connection would reach a closed port, causing a 'connection refused' error. How is that?